# IMDB dataset on Kaggle and copyright explanation

Tags: uses-of-open-data

I was surfing on kaggle and I found this dataset

https://www.kaggle.com/deepmatrix/imdb-5000-movie-dataset

it contains data from 5000 IMDB movies. I was surprised since i thought that this would be copyright infringement, could someone explain me or give me some references about scraping/copying data from other sites and making them publicly available like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely a violation of their conditions of use, unless this person got prior permission from IMDB: http://www.imdb.com/conditions
"Robots and Screen Scraping: You may not use data mining, robots, screen scraping, or similar data gathering and extraction tools on this site, except with our express written consent as noted below."

If you'd like to use their data, they do have an ftp interface:
http://www.imdb.com/interfaces

There's also the OMBb API, https://www.omdbapi.com/, the TMDb API, https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api, the MovieLens dataset, https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/, and a few others. So if you're looking to use the data yourself, I would suggest you try those sources rather than a resource that might have legal issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'm not planning any IMDB analysis I was just curious because of this finding.